# Movie where person reads ads to you

Tags: story-identification, movie

I believe this movie was futuristic, perhaps a view into what life would be like in the future. It dates from 2015 or later. In the movie (I believe) someone is eating at a diner and doesn't have the money to pay, so they ask, or use the option, to have someone come in and read product ads to them in exchange for the owed money. The character also asks the "ad read person" if they could travel across country together. The "ad read person" says something along the lines of "that will be 4000 ads".

Comment: An interesting question, but a trifle low on content. If you can, add some other details that you remember from the movie. A reader may remember one of them better than the scene that you described.

Comment: Sorry about that @InvisibleTrihedron I just hopped back on to SE.  It may sound messed up, but I also had no other detail from this show.  Just one small vague memory.

Comment: I know the feeling!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you're referencing a TV miniseries, not a movie. Is it *[Maniac (2018)](https://www.hollywoodreporter.com/live-feed/maniac-statue-extra-liberty-ad-buddy-explained-1146114), a Netflix series*, starring Emma Stone and Jonah Hill?

In it they use the firm "[Ad BUDDY](https://twitter.com/maniacnetflix/status/1045749993087283201?lang=en)" to pay for items, Annie (Emma Stone) uses it to pay for cigarettes (that's the scene I remember).

Comment: Great find. I hope you don't mind that I've added a few links and removed some of the chatter to streamline your answer.

Comment: Thank you so much!   A friend and I were kicking ourselves last night because we couldn't remember any other detail from the show!